# LogicException: You must define a binary prior to conversion

Tags: html, laravel, model-view-controller, wkhtmltopdf

snappy.php get this code

```
'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => env('"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltox\bin\wkhtmltopdf-amd64.exe"'),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

and when i try this code for test html to pdf in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {

$snappy = App::make('snappy.pdf');
$snappy->generateFromHtml('<h1>hello</h1>','exemple.pdf');
return view('welcome');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the executable path.

If Snappy don't find the executable, he get this message.

Please mark the file as executable (chmod +x on linux)

You can see this [documentation](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your binary path, if you are using Windows you must use the path like this:

```
'binary'  => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltox\bin\wkhtmltopdf-amd64.exe"'
```

And make sure the path to the .exe is correct.